# Why is "int a, b;" while "int c=a-b" not working when I gave values to "a" and "b"?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java, and this might seem easy but I just couldn't figure out what I did wrong for below.

I created a class with 3 integers a, b, and c.

```
public class Temp {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c = a - b;

    public Temp(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public int getC() {
        return c;
    }
```

Then in the main class, I created an object and gave values for a and b. But why isn't c calculating(I get 0 for result when printing out the results, as per below)?

Main:

```
public class Main122 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Temp z = new Temp(8, 7);
        System.out.println(z.getA());
        System.out.println(z.getB());
        System.out.println(z.getC());
    }
}
```

Result:

```
8
7
0
```

Please help me out, thank you!

Comment: Field initializers are executed before the body of the constructor, so at the time `a - b` is evaluated, `a` and `b` are still the default value of `0`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because **int** has default value 0 and when you declaring c, a and b had value of 0.

If you want to change the value of c you should assign  value to it like:

```
public Temp(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = this.a - this.b;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out! =)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set the `c` value at its point of declaration. You shouldn't do this for instance members. Instead,

```
public class Temp {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;

    public Temp(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = this.a - this.b;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you leave everything else unchanged, you should get

```
8
7
1
```

With your current code, you get `0` because, at the point you specify `c = a - b`, both `a` and `b` have been initialised to their default value only (so their default values are `0` for `int`s, and `0 - 0 = 0`).

Comment: Thank for helping!

Comment: @justinj Glad to help. Do consider marking the answer that helped you and closing the question. Cheers.